# Displaying data in a table on a form

Tags: c#, forms, datatable

I want to make a table on my form that displays some information. Currently, I am having an issue

My table method:

```
        private DataTable ResultTable()
    {
        Other.OrderDatabase orderDatabase = new OrderDatabase();
        string[] names = { "Order ID", "Name of order", "Price", "Date of order", "Order description" };
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            //names of columns
            table.Columns.Add(names[i]);

            foreach (Order order in orderDatabase.OrdersDatabase)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(order.OrderId, order.NameOfOrder,order.PriceOfOrder, order.DateOfOrder, order.OrderDescription);
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

My error is:

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

From my understand I have input the correct value of columns. I have 5 properties and 5 headers? I tried adding in an extra one but that didn't seem to help, maybe I am overlooking something silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting a whole row before you added all the columns.
Add the columns first, then the rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    //names of columns
    Columns.Add(names[i]);
}

foreach (Order order in orderDatabase.OrdersDatabase)
{
    table.Rows.Add(order.OrderId, order.NameOfOrder,order.PriceOfOrder, order.DateOfOrder, order.OrderDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to populate the rows each time you populate a single column. You need to define the columns before you start populating rows if I'm not mistaken.

Try moving this snippet:

```
foreach (Order order in orderDatabase.OrdersDatabase)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(order.OrderId, order.NameOfOrder,order.PriceOfOrder, order.DateOfOrder, order.OrderDescription);
            }
```

...out of this for loop, to directly below it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            //names of columns
            table.Columns.Add(names[i]);
        }
```